# Django admin url filter won't work

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I've constructed the url `http://localhost:8000/admin/myapp/rnaextracts/?biosamples__biosamplesetid__in=[57,52,51,50,49]` to link another admin page. The link points to a list view and the list is filtered by the expression passed in the url.

However, Django redirects to the proper admin list view but the query changes to `?e=1` (I think that this indicates some sort of error) and the unfiltered list is displayed.

I've tried the filter expression in Django shell and it works: `qs = RnaExtracts.objects.filter(biosamples__biosamplesetid__in=[57,52,51,50,49]`. It returns a queryset with 52 objects out of 416.

Answer (score 5):

I'm answer my own question because it seems the Django community is not so active on these issues.

I've found the answer [here](https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter). The problem was that apparently the query string shouldn't contain the values of the IN clause enclosed in square-brackets. So, the expression should be: `http://localhost:8000/admin/fantoddcc/rnaextracts/?biosamples__biosamplesetid__in=57,52,51,50,49`

Your are welcome.